# Show a default item (javascript)

Tags: javascript, onclick, hide, default, show

I want to show an default item when a page loads with this script. At the moment it is only possible when someone clicks on the 'newboxes' items.

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
      var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
                  name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
                  if (name == 'newboxes') {
                        if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                  }
                  else {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                  }
            }
      }
}


<a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1')">Te reserveren</a> | 
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2')">Bestbeoordeeld</a> | 
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3')">Nieuw verschenen</a>
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Attach it to the onLoad event `<body onload="showonlyone('newboxes1')">`

Comment: Or just setup the initial HTML as desired in the first place.